# Chrome flexbox incorrect width for percentage padding

Tags: css, flexbox

Simplified to barebones example: Chrome (40.0.2214.115 m) unexpectedly shrinks and wraps the flexbox item that contains an inner div with "A bat" text.  FF (36.0.1) respects the padding percentage as I'd expect.  Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/4q04jc2p/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test HTML</title>

<style>
body {
    display:flex;
}

#test {
    background: gray;
    padding: 0% 40%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div><div id="test">A bat</div></div>
<div>A ball</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my reading, only the *direct* child element of a flex container is a flex item, but I still thought that flex item should be correctly sized based on its own child(ren)'s content.  Thanks for any help.

Extra info: I'm having trouble finding a finite set of html+css best practice techniques for moderately complex pages, but I'm hoping flexbox is the holy grail that allows me to never use float or inline-block.  I understand the up-and-coming Template Layout (aka. CSS Grid Layout Module) is better than flexbox (http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b4580) for overall page layout, so I plan on a combination of bootstrap css library (for overall page layout) with flexbox for individual components needing good row/column layout/centering.

Then, above, I'm trying to use percentages rather than pixels for fluidity... and will add media size queries (preferably em based vs. pixel based) to be responsive.  But having this unexpected flexbox behavior already with percentage widths is not promising.  General or specific guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Firstly, the article you linked on Xanthir's blog is very subjective. It really depends on what your layout is and what your needs are. No one solution is always going to be better than another.  I use a combination of flexbox and media queries for my websites and they've met my needs.

Comment: Secondly, for the example you showed... I see how FF and Chrome are different, but I'm not sure what the use-case is for 40% padding on the left and right. To get the displays to display consistently between FF and Chrome you'll need to specify more information like `align-items`, `flex-grow`, `flex-basis`, `flex-shrink`